# Why are all menu links being transposed to underscore?

Tags: joomla, menu, 4.6.10

All menu items look like this
http://10.0.1.6/newjoomlasand3x/public_html/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/**menu_reset_1**

Instead of this
http://10.0.1.6/newjoomlasand3x/public_html/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/**menu&reset=1**

Opening up the Edit for each existing menu item is entered correctly.
Please advise

Comment: We need more information.  Is this a new site, or an old site. If the latter what was changed before it started happening. Eg, update of server software, update of Joomla, installation of a new theme, installation/ activation of a new Joomla module or CiviCRM module etc.

Comment: Upgraded from 4.6.10  but this server is still running PHP 5.3

Comment: Nothing new. Old site. Just a restore from AkeebaBackup on another server. Have done this many times on same server. Nothing new.